# How to specify server name when xmlhttprequesting from a remote server?

Tags: xmlhttprequest

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9934563/connecting-to-postgres-database-from-a-phonegap-app) question first, and the top answer. That being said, I need to issue an XMLHttpRequest to a remote server from a mobile app. Can someone show an example? I can't figure out where to specify the URL (with parameters) as shown in the answer to the previous question.

Comment: WAIT: the open method on the XHR object has parameters open(method,url,async)......if I put a full URL in the URL, is that all that's needed? I always interpreted that as just taking the location of the file on the server, assuming the page were querying its own server rather than a 3rd party server.

Answer (score 1):

XMLHttpRequests takes a URL as a parameter.  It can be a relative URL, but it can also be a fully qualified URL...except that it probably won't do what you want, due to [cross-site scripting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) protections built into most browsers.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2921242/how-to-use-jsonp-to-overcome-xss-issue) has details on solutions to this issue.

Comment: But this isn't being done from a browser-- it's being done from a PhoneGap mobile app.

Comment: Huh, might just work then.  In any case, yes, XMLHttpRequest can take a fully qualified URL.