# How to integrate postgreSQL database into cordova application?

Tags: javascript, postgresql, cordova

I need to access my data from postgreSQL database, but I don't know how to connect to it with JS. I don't want to use API for Web SQL database or similar.

Comment: After I googled "javascript postgres cordova" I got [this result](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9934563/connecting-to-postgres-database-from-a-phonegap-app). Have you, by any chance, tried doing similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer you linked is essentially correct. In order to access your data on a server you need to provide an API to the DB via REST controllers or some other mechanism.

To summarise you would need to implement this chain:

```
Cordova App <---> Web Server <---> DB on Web Server
```

However, if you are just looking for a lightweight DB to use with your cordova application then you could try using [this](https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage) plugin.